# Creating a random epoch value ranging from X days ago and now

Tags: java, random, epoch

Trying to create an epoch value, in Java, where returned value is between now and 14 days ago.
I'm using `java.util.Random.nextInt(value)` and passing in `1209600`, basically 14 days.
But the returned value is never older then today, how come?

```
public class Debug {

    private static final Random rng = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long timeSinceLastVisit = rng.nextInt(14 * 24 * 60 * 60);
        long timeOfLastVisit = now - timeSinceLastVisit;
        String date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date (timeOfLastVisit));

        System.out.println("1. " + timeOfLastVisit);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

5 sample outputs:

```
1. 1397057814065
04/09/2014 16:36:54

1. 1397058754779
04/09/2014 16:52:34

1. 1397058553618
04/09/2014 16:49:13

1. 1397058294674
04/09/2014 16:44:54

1. 1397058408390
04/09/2014 16:46:48
```

Comment: You appear to be confused between seconds and milliseconds. Your `timeSinceLastVisit` appears to be in seconds - multiply it by 1000 to get milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to use *milliseconds*, and in the line

```
long timeSinceLastVisit = rng.nextInt(14 * 24 * 60 * 60);
```

you are just getting "seconds". To solve this, multiply by `1000` so you get a value that represents milliseconds:

```
long timeSinceLastVisit = rng.nextInt(14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

**Sample Outputs:**

```
04/01/2014 21:56:04
04/03/2014 21:44:41
04/07/2014 05:38:58
03/29/2014 22:19:29
04/02/2014 08:54:51
```

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat` etc.) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Moreover, avoid performing calculations yourself if there is an OOTB (Out-Of-The-Box) API available for it e.g. [`TimeUnit#convert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#convert(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)). Given below is a `java.time` API based solution with a precision of nanosecond:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instantNow = Instant.now();

        Instant instant14DaysAgo = instantNow.minus(14, ChronoUnit.DAYS);

        // A random instant from 14 days ago until a nanosecond ago
        Instant instantRandom = instant14DaysAgo.plusNanos(
                ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(ChronoUnit.NANOS.between(instant14DaysAgo, instantNow)));
        System.out.println(instantRandom);

        // The corresponding Epoch milliseconds
        System.out.println(instantRandom.toEpochMilli());

        // The corresponding Epoch seconds
        System.out.println(TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(instantRandom.toEpochMilli(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));

        // The corresponding date-time in JVM's timezone
        ZonedDateTime zdtJvm = instantRandom.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        System.out.println(zdtJvm);

        // The corresponding date-time in a specific timezone
        ZonedDateTime zdtToronto = instantRandom.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Toronto"));
        System.out.println(zdtToronto);
    }
}
```

**Output of a sample run:**

```
2021-05-07T01:52:12.382493303Z
1620352332382
1620352332
2021-05-07T02:52:12.382493303+01:00[Europe/London]
2021-05-06T21:52:12.382493303-04:00[America/Toronto]
```

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Note:** I've updated the answer to incorporate the following good suggestion from Ole V.V.:

> Thank you for showing the modern way. While the `TimeUnit` enum
> certainly has good uses, we don’t need it here. I’d prefer the simpler
> `instantNow.minus(14, ChronoUnit.DAYS)` and then
> `instant14DaysAgo.plusNanos(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(ChronoUnit.NANOS.between(instant14DaysAgo, instantNow)))`.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Confusion about milliseconds and seconds was the reason here as recognized before but I would suggest a slightly modified solution to achieve two goals:

1. output only in full seconds (see the wished format pattern)
2. more stability regarding integer overflow (imagine, OP wants to change 14 to maybe 100)

   long timeSinceLastVisit = rng.nextInt(14 * 24 * 60 * 60) * 1000L;